# How to transform excel index match to Access - joining 4 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, vlookup

I am new to Access and I would like to ask you for help. I have data in Excel (about 50 thousand rows). On first sheet, there are my codes (case sensitive) and on other sheets(2 3 4) I have data that I "vlookup" to first sheet. The unique code is on each sheet but on sheet1 there is more codes - not all codes from sheet1 have additional info from other sheets.

Excel isn't case sensitive so I do it with combination of index and match. But 50 thousand rows is too much for Excel and I need to put it into MS Access.
On sheet1 there is unique code that is randomly generated by another program and it is combination of numbers and small and big letters. I need to display all of them and display also additional information from other sheets.

So I want to display something like this for 50 thousand rows.

```
Code(from sheet1) | FirstName(from sheet2) | LastName(from sheet3)| Adress(from sheet4)
5kj7tfR           |Jane                    | White                | London 3
```

Here are my data:
[image: my data]
The problem is that if for example the code on sheet 4 is missing (I don't have address) then Access shows me just code from sheet1 and additional info like first name is missing even if it exists on sheet2.

I tried this but when something is blank in Excel Access doesn´t show me any data from other sheets. Let's say on sheet1 are case sensitive codes, on sheet2 first names, on sheet 3 last name and on sheet4 address. I need Access to show me all codes and info from all other sheets.

```
select sheet1.code, Tab.FirstName, Tab.LastName, Tab.Adress
from Sheet1
left join
(
select sheet1.code, sheet2.FirstName, sheet3.LastName, sheet4.Adress
from ((sheet1
left join  sheet2 on (sheet2.code=sheet1.code) and (StrComp(sheet1.code,sheet2.code,0)=0))
left join sheet3 on (sheet3.code=sheet1.code) and (StrComp(sheet1.code,sheet3.code,0)=0))
left join sheet4 on (sheet4.code=sheet1.code) and (StrComp(sheet1.code,sheet4.code,0)=0)
) as Tab
on Sheet1.ID = Tab.ID --...these IDs made Access while importing Excel to Access.
```

How can I show all codes with all data even if some cell is empty?

Thank you!

Comment: Where does Tab data come from? Probably the ID fields should not be linked. Autonumber fields seldom are in sync. Edit question to show sample data.

Comment: Need a dataset of all possible code values for the sheets to join to.

Comment: I added some additional information to the question. I can't  write all possible codes because they are unique - I have thousands of them. 

I used complementary Tab that assist me with joining tables because when I just join tables without this Tab (which is combination of joins)  it shows me just rows which have all info from all sheets). Whis this helpful Tab I reached that codes from Sheet1 are shown even if there is no data for this code in other sheets. But Access shows either code from sheet1 with all info in other colums or code from sheet1 and all other colums in Access are empty.

Comment: Data should be provided as text tables in question, not an image. However, I can see that Sheet1 has all possible codes. The other sheets should have no problem joining to Sheet1 to achieve desired output, assuming code is unique in all tables. But I've never had to consider case before, I will have to do some testing.

Comment: You did not show Tab dataset nor how you constructed it.

Comment: Tab is made by joining tables. You can see it in the script. ((sheet1
left join  sheet2 on (sheet2.code=sheet1.code) and (StrComp(sheet1.code,sheet2.code,0)=0))
left join sheet3 on (sheet3.code=sheet1.code) and (StrComp(sheet1.code,sheet3.code,0)=0))
left join sheet4 on (sheet4.code=sheet1.code) and (StrComp(sheet1.code,sheet4.code,0)=0)
) as Tab.
Probably this will be the problem that it is showing all data from sheets2 - sheet3 or none of them. But this was way how to show data from sheet1 without dupicates

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `as Tab` in SQL. I tried that query and get error `more than one Sheet1.ID`. But you don't show ID fields in tables. If these are autonumber fields then they have no relationship and linking them makes no sense. When I add the ID fields, query triggers input popup for Tab.ID.

Answer (score 0):

My research indicates cannot force case sensitivity on linking fields in Access. StrComp() is used to apply filter criteria and force case-INsensitive matches between two tables to be rejected. I can get a UNION to show all case-sensitive matches but cannot group on code values because grouping is not case sensitive. Only option I can see involves VBA converting text to HEX and using that value to join, sort, group.

Place this function in a general module (found at [Case-Sensitive Sort](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-records-in-case-sensitive-order-8FEA1DE4-6189-40E7-9359-00CD7D7845C0).)).

```
Function StrToHex(S As Variant) As Variant
'
' Converts a string to a series of hexadecimal digits.
' For example, StrToHex(Chr(9) & "A~") returns 09417E.
'
   Dim Temp As String, I As Integer
      If VarType(S) <> 8 Then
         StrToHex = S
      Else
         Temp = ""
      For I = 1 To Len(S)
         Temp = Temp & Format(Hex(Asc(Mid(S, I, 1))), "00")
      Next I
         StrToHex = Temp
      End If
End Function
```

Calling that function in query returns desired output. Copy/paste or type into SQLView of query builder. I initially built query with joins on code fields then switched to SQLView and added in function calls. **DO NOT OPEN QUERY IN DESIGN VIEW.** Access query designer cannot resolve these joins. Would have to join nested subqueries to enable Design View.

Note I have spelled `address` with two d's, modify as you see fit.

```
SELECT Sheet1.code, [time], [type of error], FirstName, LastName, age, address
FROM Sheet4 RIGHT JOIN (Sheet3 RIGHT JOIN (Sheet2 RIGHT JOIN Sheet1 
     ON StrToHex([Sheet2].[code]) = StrToHex([Sheet1].[code])) 
     ON StrToHex([Sheet3].[code]) = StrToHex([Sheet1].[code])) 
     ON StrToHex([Sheet4].[code]) = StrToHex([Sheet1].[code]);
```